# How to copy Quickbooks production data over to the sandbox environment?

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I need the company data copied over from production to the sandbox environment to test an API integration.  I need access to the live data, but I do not want to make changes to the live environment yet.

I've tried exporting the company data (Internet explorer was required), but the file downloaded didn't appear on my computer.  When I was finally able to get the file, it didn't save with an extension so Quickbooks desktop wouldn't open it.  The online converter would recognize it, but it would hang after selecting it.

I've also tried exporting the list individually, but that doesn't keep the original `Id`.

[The question on the developer community has been stale for a while.](https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/question/0D5G000004Dk6vpKAB/how-do-i-create-a-sandbox-company-from-an-existing-qb-online-production-company)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After emailing Quickbooks support, there is an unsupported way [here](https://github.com/minimul/qbo-sandbox).

The idea is, after you create the sandbox empty the data.  Then you can copy everything over in batches.

Otherwise it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this. Read the response from Intuit on the thread you linked:

> "... there is no way to move data from a production QBO account to a sandbox"
>
> "Thanks for the feedback, we don have an ETA at this point."